# How to update bundle key value?

Tags: java, android

I have a situation to update `Bundle` value, like below:

```
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
dataBundle.putString("name",object.getString("name"));
dataBundle.putString("email",object.getString("email"));
dataBundle.putString("id",object.getString("_id"));
dataBundle.putString("otp",object.getString("otp"));
```

Now user can send the the request for re-otp, and i have to update `otp`, is there any way to update?

Comment: If you want this to be on another activity, try using `onActivityResult` and `startActivityForResult`.  Try to avoid mutating existing objects as much as you can, Android is designed over immutable messages between Activities through Intents.

Comment: i know there is alternative ways, i want to know that, is there any way to update single key of bundle? i have searched over google but nothing found about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update/override the bundle key value just setting the new value in same bundle coresponding to same key
(It will don't affect on other key values of this bundle)

```
// This will update value of otp with "newotp" in dataBundle
dataBundle.putString("otp","newotp");
```

Answer (score 1):

Write to shared preferences because using shared preference will be easy to update and read the data.

Write & Update Data

```
     SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor. putString("otp", object.getString("otp"));
        editor.commit();
```

Read Data

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String otp= sharedPref.getString("otp", defaultValue);
```